# Serverless and GlobalSecondaryIndexes - Query condition missed key schema element with dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, aws-serverless

I tried to create GlobalSecondaryIndexes with serverless and query for it later. I get an

```
Query condition missed key schema element: id
```

error doing this, which makes sense but my plan is to query for all elements at a specific day.

```
  var params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_LIGHTHOUSE,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'fetchDate = :fetchDate',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':fetchDate': { S: '2019-05-13' }
    }
  };

  const dbResult = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise()
  console.log(dbResult)
```

This is the serverless part for the dynamodb. Probably here is something missing?

```
DynamoDbTableExpenses:
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      -
        AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
      -
        AttributeName: fetchDate
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      -
        AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: fetchDateIndex
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: fetchDate
            KeyType: HASH
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE_LIGHTHOUSE}
```

In the web frontend it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `IndexName` attribute. Try:

```
var params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_LIGHTHOUSE,
    IndexName: 'fetchDateIndex',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'fetchDate = :fetchDate',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':fetchDate': '2019-05-13'
    }
};
```

See [API Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

> The Query operation finds items based on primary key values. You can
>   query any table or secondary index that has a composite primary key (a
>   partition key and a sort key).

Comment: I now get an error:  ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type ... How would I query then for multiple e.g. data + another value?

Comment: I've updated original answer. ExpressionAttributeValues should be `':fetchDate': '2019-05-13'`

Comment: just found out that the S: is not needed, too. Thanks